# Scrapy multiple proxies

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am planning to use multiple proxies for scraping. I wanted to know if the setting `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` would be applied to each proxy IP or the website IP.

Also wanted to know if there are other throttling strategies that can be used to crawl properly?

edit: I checked out [Throttling requests with multiple proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919236/throttling-requests-with-multiple-proxies) and there's nothing mentioned about how concurrency is handled in Scrapy. It says about writing custom logic for doing it.

Comment: In general, it is better to scrape without proxies, like well-behaved search robots do. If a provider wishes to IP block you, they are generally within their rights to do that. If you believe you have a special case where proxies are justified, would you add details to the question?

Comment: Well, I did some scraping with proxies and it was very slow. I then went on to scrape without proxies and it was much better. Am dropping the idea of proxy based scraping as of now.

Comment: OK. One thing to remember is that, if you are making a large number of HTTP requests to a single domain, you need it to be slow - otherwise you are utilising a large fraction of someone else's system resources. This usage could be so heavy as to amount to a denial of service attack. Thus, if you are scraping many sites, scrape them in rotation, so that any one site is not hit more than, say, every three seconds. If you are scraping just one site, you will need to add a manual delay.

Comment: Yes, I have added concurrent requests setting along with manual delay. Thank you @halfer for the insight.

Comment: Ah, concurrent requests may be a problem. There is no value in setting a few seconds of delay between operations if you are using parallel cURL requests. If you parallelise 10 requests, for example, it will do 10 requests in one go with no delay in between, then it will do one delay, then another 10 hits in one burst, etc.