# How to throttle requests to sites instead of to proxy server in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I am using a proxy and have set AUTO_AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED to True. I had the impression that scrapy throttles the sites which I am crawling, instead it seems like scrapy throttles requests to proxy itself. How do I throttle requests to sites instead of proxy?

Update: I am manually setting proxy in meta while making each request, instead of using the proxy middleware.

Comment: what do you mean by `How do I throttle requests to sites instead of proxy?`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919236/throttling-requests-with-multiple-proxies) SO question/answer should give you a way how to do it.

Comment: While similar, that's not actually related. This is about measuring latency between the proxy and the target, while that is about setting different throttling rules for different proxys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to do solely from the spider side. By looking at the [throttling algorithm](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html#throttling-algorithm) and at the [AutoThrottle extension source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/7c9e32213db2ce757c784e7c29e30caa57dc3d48/scrapy/extensions/throttle.py#L9), you can see that the delay being used is the time difference between sending a request and getting back a response. Everything that happens in between is added up to this delay (including the proxy delay). 
To further verify this, consider the steps:

1. AutoThrottle is using latency information from the response, found
   in the `response.meta['download_latency]` (see [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/7c9e32213db2ce757c784e7c29e30caa57dc3d48/scrapy/extensions/throttle.py#L42-L47))
2. The latency information ('download_latency') is set in the dedicated callback once the download is completed, by subtracting the start time from the current time (see [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/7c9e32213db2ce757c784e7c29e30caa57dc3d48/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L354)).
3. The start time is actually set just before the download agent is instructed to download the request, which means everything in between is added up to the final latency (see [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/7c9e32213db2ce757c784e7c29e30caa57dc3d48/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L329-L333)).

If you want to actually throttle according to target latency through a proxy, this will have to be handled by the proxy itself. I suggest using some of the managed proxy pool solutions like [Crawlera](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera).